# Is there an easy way for users to print Flash (Open Flash Charts) from their browser?

Tags: php, mysql, flash, printing, open-flash-chart

Is there any easy way to print Flash Charts (Open Flash Charts 2) within a web page. Flash doesn't seem to print at all.

I'm maintaining a health site for a client, and we use Open Flash Charts to draw multiple line charts for patients dynamic data. The client would like for patients to be able to easily print these charts, although Flash doesn't appear to be printable (unless I'm missing something).

Unfortunately I can't provide a link to the page as an example at the moment as the patient data is obviously confidential and is locked away behind usernames and passwords. I should be able to however provide some edited html of one of the flash chart pages if necesarry.

I'm open to suggestions, as I've never come accross anyone wanting to print flash before, and it's not something I've ever personally wanted to do either.

Comment: What server side technology are you using?

Comment: The site is sat on a dedicated linux server using PHP & MySQL. It's actually a Joomla driven site although this patient area is a custom coded component I've built.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! convert the flash to images: http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/save-image-js.php

There is code by Sylvain Abelard used with the Open Flash Chart 2 system by John Glazebrook

You can use this function

```
OFC.jquery.rasterize('my_chart', 'my_chart');
```

to convert a flash graph to an image which can be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Strange I would thing you could print anything that's on the screen try

- CRTL + P
- or Right Click the Chart and select
  Print

Tested both and seem to work fine for me, tested this site: http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/

Comment: Ahh - that would depend on your browser. For once, this seems to be something that Internet Explorer can handle just fine, and Firefox can't

Answer (score 0):

Can you alter the code in charts? If so, you can easily write some ActionScript code to print your data the way you like, check `PrintJob` class.